# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Closing When Icon Tapped

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When my page is small enough to show the collapsible navbar, you can click or tap the icon and it will open the navbar. BUT if you click or tap it again, it won't close. I am not sure why.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top mb-2">
            <a href="/mwlas/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/mwlas/_img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                <span class="d-none d-sm-block float-right ml-3">Made with Love And Sarcasm</span></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/mwlas/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/mwlas/portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/mwlas/shop" class="nav-link">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/mwlas/blog" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"
                            onclick="location.href='/mwlas/login.php'">Login
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you, but it seems to be working

Comment: I noticed that in the code snippet too . . . and yet it isn't here https://madewithloveandsarcasm.com/

Comment: Looks like you're importing the scripts more than once. Try fixing this first

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting that.

Comment: No problem. It seems to be working now :)

Comment: Yessir! Give the answer and you shall receive your reward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of your page, you were importing the scripts (`jQuery`, `popper` and `bootstrap.js`) twice.

That led to some issues/conflicts. Make sure you import exactly as the [Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) guide describes

Import the scripts only once and the problem should disappear.